# Issue with attaching a new Surface to LibVLC

Tags: android, vlc, libvlc

I have been using libvlc 0.9.9 in an Android app for a while now. It has been working well, except for 4.4 devices and below hanging in some scenarios when calling vlc.stop(). It looks like the issue relates to the link here: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.video.videolan.vlc.devel/96116

I have attempted to upgrade to the newest version and all works well, except during device rotation. Here is the strategy I am using.

I am using a retainedFragment inside an Activity. I am creating the vlc player inside the retainedFragment. On rotation, I allow the activity to be destroyed, and the retainedFragment to be re-attached. The reason I am doing this is because the views are completely different for portrait and landscape. I would much prefer to use this approach rather than not allowing the activity to be destroyed and having to manually add and remove the portrait vs landscape views. I also did this in order to keep the video playing in the background while waiting for the new surface to come available.

In 0.9.9, I was able to call libvlc.detach() in SurfaceDestroyed and libvlc.attachSurface(mSurface, this) in SurfaceChanged(). By doing this, libvlc would attach itself to the newly created surface. However, the new versions of libvlc I have tried, including the most current, will not reattach to the newly created surface. Here's an example of what shows in the logs.

04-13 14:05:18.860 14767-15341/com.sparc.stream E/Surface﹕ dequeueBuffer failed (No such device)
04-13 14:05:18.860 14767-15341/com.sparc.stream W/VLC﹕ [7d8909cc] yuv_rgb_neon filter: can't get output picture

I'm not sure if anyone else is using the retained fragment method, but if so, could you share if you have gotten this working. I can work on posting code examples if that would help.

Thanks!

Tyler

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get an answer on VLC forums. Here is the answer if anyone else has this issue...

The newest versions of libvlc added a setVideoTrack() method.

In order to set the player to a new surface you can:

`setVideoTrack(-1);
 setVideoTrack(0); //or 1 if your video track is 1`